# Passing a function to a constructor without bracket arguments

Tags: scala, curly-braces

I can write the following in scala

```
def foo[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) = {}

val x = foo { (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j }
```

But say I wanted to do something similar in a constructor:

```
class C[P1, P2, R](f: (P1, P2) => R) {
  def apply(p1: P1, p2: P2): R = f(p1, p2)
}
```

Then to define an object of type C I need to do the following for it to compile:

```
object MyObj extends C( { (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j })
```

Why do I need the brackets and is there any way I could avoid using them and define my object thus:

```
object MyObj extends C { (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can omit the `{}` rather than omiting the `()`, like this:

```
object MyObj extends C( (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j )
```

The longer answer is that ability to write `foo{x}` rather than `foo(x)` is specific to function application and does not apply to constructors. The details are [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#function-applications) but basically you can use an expression in `{}` when applying a function that takes a single argument.